# passportjs bearer strategy, load page anyway

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js for authentication in my web app. I am following the example given  [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/), that is the following code:

```
app.get('/api/me', 
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });
```

now, the thing is that the code inside `function(req, res)` is called only with the correct access_token. If the login is wrong the function is never called and it just returns "Unauthorized". Is there a way to execute the function anyway? For example something like this:

```
app.get('/api/me', 
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    if(req.user){
      res.json(req.user);
    } else {
      res.json({ error: 'whatever' })
    }
  });
```

which obviously does not work as the function is never called!

[here](http://pastie.org/9430794) is a pastie from my code. I would basically like my router to render the page anyway, even with wrong credentials.

Answer (score 0):

From [Passport's authenticate page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), the `authenticate` method accepts an optional custom callback function as its third argument.

I haven't tried out with a `Bearer` strategy, but I don't think it will be any different.
BUT bear in mind that if you this callback function, you have to handle the `login` process yourself, using `res.logIn()`

So

```
app.get('/api/me', 
    passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false },
      function(err, user,info) {
         if (err) { return next(err); } // If there's an error the process
         if (!user) { return res.json({ error: 'user not found' }) } // If the user's not found
         req.logIn(user, function(err) { // User exists !
               if (err) { return next(err); }
               return res.json(req.user);
         });
     });
 );
```

Does that help you ?